# cmd.ExecuteReader() with SQLite is slow but fast in SQLite Manager

Tags: performance, sqlite, sqlitemanager, executereader

I planned to use SQLite as local database.
I created a complex Select statement with "group by" and "order by" in SQLite Manager (Firefox AddIn). 
The query run in about **600 ms** in SQLite Manager.
In my C# application i've created a SQLiteCommand with the same query and the cmd.ExecuteReader() method takes about **60 seconds** to finish.
I'm using the System.Data.SQLite.dll. Neither the "ANALYZE" nor the "VACUUM" command improved the execution time.

Can anyone tell my how to get the same execution time as in SQLite Manager?

Matti

Comment: Are you using the same SQLite version?

Comment: i was using the version 1.0.66 and just updated to version 1.0.84.0 which is the newest and the execution time was reduced to 40 seconds. Still to much.

Comment: Version 1.0.84.0 of the ADO.NET adapter uses version 3.7.15.2 of SQLite. Which version of SQLite is used by your version of Firefox? (run `SELECT sqlite_version();`)

Comment: SELECT sqlite_version(); ==> "3.7.14.1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simplified my query by just using the select and did the grouping in code via linq. Thats not the best solution but it worked for me